# PgAdmin 4 cannot connect to the server error in PostgreSQL database in Windows 10

Tags: windows, pgadmin-4

I have installed Postgresql 13.2.2 X64 database server in my Windows 10 computer. After installation, whenever I want to run the PgAdmin 4 tool it shows the below error. I tried a lot to fix the problem. Can anyone help me to solve the problem.

**Error Message**

> Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin
> 4\python\python.exe" Runtime Config File:
> "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json" pgAdmin
> Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
> Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin
> 4\web\pgAdmin4.py" pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py" Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "../web/pgAdmin4.py", line 98, in 
> app = create_app()   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_*init*_.py", line 347, in create_app
> if not os.path.exists(SQLITE_PATH) or get_version() == -1:   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin
> 4\web\pgadmin\setup\db_version.py", line 19, in get_version
> return version.value AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

[image]

Comment: I had the same error. After re-installing different version of pgAdmin I've when to the log files and found the logs saying the same as above.
Finally I've removed the pgAdmin folder from the C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin and restarted the pgAdmin and it worked..




Good luck

Comment: Thanks. It's working.

Answer (score 1):

I too have the same problem. So I deleted the "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin"
directory and restarted the pgadmin. After that issue got fixed and the version I use is pgadmin4-5.2-x64